# Keep queried SQL data in one state while updating

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, web-scraping, schedule

The use case as follows:

- I scrape data from a bigger database (only read access) on a fixed schedule and it takes roughly 30mins to 1 hour
- the resulted table will always have >20k rows, the data can be grouped by a dataset_id column which is constricted to 4 values like an enum
- when I query all of the rows of one dataset_id let's say `SELECT * FROM db WHERE dataset_id = A` it is essential that all the records are from the same scrape (so I shouldn't have mixed data from different scrapes)

The question is how would I persist the old data until the new scrape is finished and only  then switch to get the new data while deleting the old scrape?

I have thought of the following option:

- have 2 tables and switch between them when a newer scrape is finished

Comment: Identify "the scrape" ?

Comment: Option #1 is to lock the entire table; will work but it's not very desirable. Option #2, you can add a `scrape_number` column to mark all the rows within the scrape; then you need to make sure other threads don't touch (insert/delete) into your scrape; should work well.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille in my case the scrape is related to an array of shapes and I'm matching the data from the big db to check if it is in a given shape. So from the bigger db I only want to save the data that is passing a condition (that's solved). The saved data however will then be displayed in a dashboard and the data shown must be from the same scrapping process.

Comment: I meant it like @TheImpaler, give each scrape an identifier, a column in the result table.  Once a new scrape has been registered, you can delete the older ones.

Comment: Thanks guys this is what I ended up doing and it works perfectly, please answer so I could give you the answer upvote.